# OpenCL clEnqueueNDRangeKernel work_dim VS global_work array elements

Tags: opencl, gpu

I'm new in OpenCL and I'm trying to understand this piece of code:

```
size_t global_work1[3]  = {BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1};
size_t local_work1[3]  = {BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1};

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmd_queue, diag, 2, NULL, global_work1, local_work1, 0, 0, 0);
```

So, in the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` 2 dimension for the kernel are specified (`work_dim` field), this means that:

- the dimension 0 kernel got a number of threads equal to `BLOCK_SIZE` and only one group (I guess the number of groups can be calculated in this way => `( global_work1[0] ) / ( local_work1[0] )` ).
- the dimension 1 Kernel got a number of threads equal to 1 and only one group.

and also why a dimension of 2 is specified in the queue instruction when three are the elements in `global_work1` and `local_work1`.

Comment: Probably only first two elements of those arrays will be used as a 2D execution.

Comment: yes but it sounds strange, especially for what concern the the second element of the arrays.... 1 thread in 1 group..... doesn't make any sense. Probably there is a fault in my OpenCL understanding. Thanks for the comment !!!!!

Comment: I agree that this code does NOT look correct.

Comment: Its executing BLOCK_SIZE x 1 sized blocks.

Comment: So you're suggesting that only the firsts elements of the array are considered? the others elements are ignored because are one??

Comment: They aren't ignored. You told the enqueue function to take notice of the first two. It's just the second is 1. n*1 is a valid size just like a 1-D launch of 1 work-item would be valid. It is equivalent to requesting 1 dimension, but not really the same as ignoring the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling CL:
"Run this kernel, in this queue, with 2D and these global/local sizes"

CL is just getting the first 2 dimensions of the argument, and ignoring the 3rd one.

About the difference between 1D and 2D. There is none. Since OpenCL kernels launched as 1D do not fail on `get_global_id(1)` and `get_global_id(2)` calls. They will just return 0. So there is no difference at all, apart from the hint that the kernel will probably support bigger sizes for the 2nd dimension argument (ie: 512x128)